# How to make text solid over an ellipse using transparency specifically using Opacity

Tags: java, text, javafx, opacity, ellipse

so I've been trying for days to get this right but I can't get the `Text text = new Text("Name");` to show clearly over my Ellipse I'm trying to use the `setOpacity` nothing else please, so other suggestions will be ignored. I've been trying for weeks and it's starting to really piss me off here's my code the closest I got to it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ellipseICE07 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
       Pane pane = new Pane();

       Text text = new Text("Name");
       text.setLayoutY(205);
       text.setLayoutX(255);
       text.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
       text.setOpacity(2.0);
       text.setFont(Font.font("Cambria", FontWeight.BOLD, 34));
       pane.getChildren().add(text);

       for(int o = 0; o < 180; o += 10){
           Ellipse ep = new Ellipse(300, 200, 100, 3);
           ep.setRotate(o);
           ep.setFill(null);
           ep.setOpacity(0.3);
           ep.setStroke(Color.RED);
           pane.getChildren().add(ep);
       }




       for(int i = 0; i < 180; i += 5){
           Ellipse ep1 = new Ellipse(300, 200, 100, 3);
           ep1.setRotate(i);
           ep1.setFill(null);
           ep1.setOpacity(0.3);
           ep1.setStroke(Color.RED);
           pane.getChildren().add(ep1);

       }


       Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Please Help.

Comment: "I'm trying to use the setOpacity nothing else please, so other suggestions will be ignored. " The thing is, the opacity is not actually the problem. So what do you want us to do?

Comment: what is the problem then cause when I run the program if you run it in netbeans or eclipse you'll see that the Name isn't solid over the shape? so then how would you go about it, if you were to go another route that's pretty simple, what am I missing?

Comment: Add the text after you add the ellipses, so it appears on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what about this version of your code? Is that closer to your expectation?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ellipseICE07 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        Text text = new Text("Name");
        text.setLayoutY(205);
        text.setLayoutX(255);
        text.setStroke(null);
        text.setFill(Color.BLUE);
//      text.setOpacity(2.0);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Cambria", FontWeight.BOLD, 34));

        for (int o = 0; o < 180; o += 10) {
            Ellipse ep = new Ellipse(300, 200, 100, 3);
            ep.setRotate(o);
            ep.setFill(null);
//          ep.setOpacity(0.3);
            ep.setStroke(Color.RED);
            pane.getChildren().add(ep);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 180; i += 5) {
            Ellipse ep1 = new Ellipse(300, 200, 100, 3);
            ep1.setRotate(i);
            ep1.setFill(null);
//          ep1.setOpacity(0.3);
            ep1.setStroke(Color.RED);
            pane.getChildren().add(ep1);

        }

        pane.getChildren().add(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: LOL man I can't believe that's all i had to do I tried addALL(ep, ep1, text); but it wouldnt work cause of the brackets around the for loops thanks so muuch!